# refresh data in session jsf2, PrimeFaces

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, refresh

I have two xhtml pages: the first allow to store new order, the second allow to list all of orders stored in the database.

For specific purposes, I have `sessionManeged` in the second page and the problem is when I save a new order and I go in the second page it doesn't get refresh because data are stored in sessions.

Can you suggest me a method to refresh data (re_run query to database) when a new order is stored?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using `@RequestScoped` for the specific item page and `@ViewScoped` for listing, connected with GET parameters to obtain data (because you cannot inject ViewScoped in RequestScoped.

Then use `@PostConstruct` to initialize your list from database, like

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    someListElement = facade.findAll();
}
```

Comment: I found the question very hard to understand, but I initially understood that the OP is more asking how to push changes from server to client. Changing a property of a session scoped bean is namely *too* obvious to be the OP's concrete problem.